# Accessing devise's current_user from library code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I've created a class in my rails app's lib directory. That class needs access to Devise's current_user.

I also should point out that this lib class is frequently accessed from model code, and therefore cannot have the current_user passed into it.

How can I achieve this?

Peter.

Comment: You can pass current_user object from controller to your model where you need to work with

Answer (score 1):

Where are you using your library? Are you calling it from any controller method? If so, you should pass the current user as a parameter to your library class constructor, and work with it there. current_user is a controller helper. It expects a valid authenticated session and therefore only makes sense when used from there and in the app flow. Using current_user for any background/script task would not make sense, anyway.

Comment: I am using this library from both controller and model code. Therefore passing current_user around is not really an option. Is there some module that I can include?

Comment: pass a user, not the current user then. current_user is not accessible in the model for a reason: the notion of a current user only makes sense in the session scope, hence request scope, hence controller scope. The model doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: You're not understanding me. Passing current_user to the library is not an option because the library needs to be usable from the model which does not have access to current_user (for a good reason, I know). And I can't pass the current user to the model because I don't control the contract of the methods being called (like 'find' and 'save').

Comment: In the context of your application, when do you need to pass the current user to your library and what should this library accomplish? I assume that this library should not keep state (that is your current user). Without more inside information I'd say, pass the current user as an argument to the model, and then delegate to your library.

Comment: My rails app does not have a database. Instead I have a legacy API to contend with for my model objects. The library in question is the ruby wrapper for this legacy API. One of the consequences of this is that I need the currently logged in user's credentials in order to communicate with this API.

Comment: From my experience with ruby API wrappers, the user credentials need to be passed to the wrapper. And then you pass the wrapper around.

Comment: That isn't the case here. I need to pass the credentials on each transaction.

Comment: so you'd have to instantiate a wrapper for every request, which doesn't sound wrong.

Comment: Yeah, the trouble with instantiating a wrapper for every request is that methods like model.find() and model.save() need an extra current_user parameter.